# ToolBar title in center

Tags: ios, iphone, uitoolbar

Here is a screenshot of my toolbar. I want to set the text in center. It is displaying not in center.
[image]

Comment: vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Please give some explanation for your question.

Answer (score 1):

for navigationbar you can use

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:-20 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

in the viewDidLoad of your controller.

For the toolbar you can create a customview with button and place it wherever you want with a CGRect.